# Vintage mode sublime text перемещение

Tags: vim, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

При перемешении по файлу через <kbd>j k h l</kbd> я могу только на один символ, то есть я не могу зажать <kbd>j</kbd> и перемещаться по строкам вниз, приходится постоянно нажимать <kbd>j</kbd>.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: [**Не воспроизводится**](http://i.imgur.com/5UH542j.gifv) на Windows 10, всё работает нормально. Если установить, как сказали ниже, чистую версию Sublime Text 3, проблема остаётся?

Answer (score 2):

> Как решить эту проблему?

например, пользоваться программой *vim*.

насколько мне известно, у неё есть пакеты/сборки под все более или менее популярные дистрибутивы операционных систем.

Comment: спасибо, помогло, палец вверх

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy: если помогло, то кроме «палец вверх» вы можете принять ответ как верный (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно странное поведение, которое я не встречал ни в `st2`, ни в `st3` на `ubuntu` или `debian`. Перемещение отлично работает с зажатыми клавишами, или же при помощи множителей (типа `<kbd>5j</kbd>`).

К сожалению, по вашему запросу неизвестна ваша ОС. Возможно проблема в ней. Также мешать могут какие-либо настройки вашего ST, или сторонние плагины и их настройки. Попробуйте запустить чистый ST, и включить в нем vintage mode - будет ли сохраняться поведение?

Comment: Mac, изредка когда устанавливаю саблям и работает нормально, но в большинстве случаев приходится нажимать ещё раз клавишу чтобы сделать действие